# How to define if greater then in java string

Tags: java

In the following method I need to define that only set the value if its not null and if the value is greater than "0.00"  How do I define that.

```
 String postagePaid1 = trackInfo.getPostage();
                    if(postagePaid1 != null && ????) {
                        claim.setClPtsPostageFee(new BigDecimal(postagePaid1));
                    }
```

Comment: What if the string doesn't contain digits at all, or doesn't contain *just* digits? E.g., `"foo"`? Or `"1.17€"`?

Comment: The string only contains digits and decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use String values as doubles during comparison. String comparison is done in *natural order*, so `"1111"` will be lesser than `"9"`.

In your case, use `Double.parseDouble(doubleString)` and then compare values.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do numeric comparisons with Strings as it doesn't make sense in the String world, only with numbers. So first check that it's not null, and if not, convert it to a double via `Double.parseDouble(...)`

```
if (someStr != null && !someStr.trim().isEmpty()) {
  try {
    double someNumber = Double.parseDouble(someStr.trim());
    if (someNumber > 0.0) {
       // ***** here you are ****
    }
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
      // some action if String is not numeric
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `postagePaid1` contains only **double** type value ,you have to convert the string to double type by using following code in order to be able to do comparison

```
Double.parseDouble(postagePaid1)
```

so if statement become :

```
 if(postagePaid1 != null && Double.parseDouble(postagePaid1)>0.00) {
```